# Use jackson to convert json containing integer timestamp to 'java.util.Date' with default typing enabled

Tags: java, jackson

I am facing a difficulty while trying to convert JSON object in the my java object. I am getting the following response from the server (I cannot modify the server side things):

```
["com.transer.money.MyResponse",
  {
    movements:
      ["java.util.ArrayList",
        [
          ["com.transer.money.Movement",
            {
              threshold:
                ["com.transer.money.Amount",
                  {
                    value:["java.math.BigDecimal",4.],
                    currencyCode:"USD"
                  }
                ],
              minAmount:null,
              ,
              sourceBalance:
                ["com.transer.money.Issuer",
                  {
                    Id:"EAA063862",
                    currencyCode:"USD
                  }
                ],
              sourceEndpoint:
                ["com.transer.money.BusinessEndpoint",
                  {
                    currencyCode:"USD",
                    clientId:"1",
                    appId:"62"
                  }
                ],
              destinationEndpoint:
                ["com.transer.money.BankEndpoint",
                  {
                    currencyCode:"USD",
                    customerId:"A06P3BKSNFY",
                    Id:"4cfbbd47"
                  }
                ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      ],
    transactionId:"A82319",
    created:355643314
  }
]
```

While deserializing I am getting the error:

```
Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.util.Date
```

My code to do the same is as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
com.transer.money.MyResponse.resp = mapper.readValue(jsonString, com.transer.money.MyResponse.class);
```

A if I omit the line `mapper.enableDefaultTyping(org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);` , I get the error 
`Cannot deserialize instance of com.transfer.money.MyResponse out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]`

Will really appreciate any response here as I have already tried various things but nothing seems to be working with the date.

Thanks

Comment: One note is that your json doesn't pass validation - to check this you can find json parsers/validators online and run your json through one of these to see if it's valid. Another note is that it would be helpful to also post the class as well.

Comment: @Eugen - I have only pasted a portion of json I receive from the service, so I might have missed some bracket/parenthesis. Otherwise I have verified the structure of actual response, it is correct.

Comment: Also, what class do you want? MyResponse?

Comment: First - what service are you using to validate the json? I tried it in 3 different services and it failed - you can easily paste it in: http://jsonlint.com/ to check. Second - yes, MyResponse and whatever other class the json uses. I can see that there are 6 classes in your json - so simplifying the json in the original question is also a good idea. The whole point is to be able to actually run the example and see it fail - if the example is simple - than people are going to be able to run it and help you much easier. Also - the problem will likely be the same with the simpler json.